# Save Large files from a Web Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, filesaver.js

I am starting developing a google-chrome app to be used to write a large file (128GB), locally on the file system. Basically I receive a binary vector from a websocket and I would like to write this data to the file system to be used by another application later.

I studied the FileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) and the StreamSaver.js (https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) to resolve this problem but FileSaver.js is limite to the memory I can use and the FileSaver.js needs to be connected to the Internet and sometimes the application does not have access to the Internet.

Question?
Is a google chrome plugin or app the best solution for it? I don't mind to be limited to use only google-chrome. I do not need a portable solution.
Is it possible to do something similar without develop a google chrome app?

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem